# WriteFile with Overlapped IO and ERROR_DISK_FULL?

Tags: windows, file, asynchronous, winapi, storage

Wonder if anyone knows the internal design of `WriteFile()` (Storage Team Here?) with overlapped IO for file on on a disk drive/file system.  Clearly when using the system buffer and standard synchronous `WriteFile()` it checks for full disk and allocates space prior to returning because the system cache holding the actual data is written later (a problem causes a delayed write error from the OS).

So the question is: would the same be true when using `OVERLAPPED` structure for asynchronous `WriteFile()` that expands the file beyond free space?  e.g. It would return `ERROR_DISK_FULL` right away before pending the IO?

The reason to know is for recovery of freeing disk space, or inserting new media, and resuming the writes.  If done this way, it's fairly straight forward, if after pending the IO, you could have a bunch of queued IO that then has to be synchronized and additional information tracked for all queued items in case moving to new media to adjust the offsets and such.

TIA!!

Comment: Seems like something you could easily test yourself with a few lines of code. Fill up your free disk space, then perform an async write and see how it reacts.

Comment: *using OVERLAPPED structure* not make I/O asynchronous, so here this is unrelated. are your I/O request complete just with error `ERROR_DISK_FULL` or you first got `ERROR_IO_PENDING` and then it complete with `ERROR_DISK_FULL` this is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if no enough disk space for complete write operation - you got `ERROR_DISK_FULL` (`STATUS_DISK_FULL`) when I/O operation will complete. are filesystem driver just complete your write request with `STATUS_DISK_FULL` (converted to `ERROR_DISK_FULL`) or first return `STATUS_PENDING` (converted to `ERROR_IO_PENDING` by win32) and then complete I/O with `STATUS_DISK_FULL` - this is **undefined**. can be both. final status will be `ERROR_DISK_FULL` but you cannot assume are operation will complete synchronous or asynchronous

Comment: I take it that using `TAG`ed queued IO is handled at a lower level within the disk driver and has nothing to do with the higher level API ?

Comment: @user3161924 - `STATUS_DISK_FULL` (`ERROR_DISK_FULL`) this is file system error code. nothing comon with disk drivers (on disk level at all there is no such thing as a disk is full - disk have only size). anout *TAGed queued IO* dont understand

Comment: SATA/PATA `queued` IO requests use a `TAG`.  Must be at disk level driver that issues disk commands that handles that separate from any `WriteFile()` API call.

Comment: @user3161924 - but how disk level is related to your question ? disk can not be full or not full

Answer (score 3):

What you mean by asynchronous file operations (`WriteFile()` etc.) - these operations are only asynchronous for the caller. Internally they work the same way as synchronous (blocking) ones. The implementation of a blocking call invokes the non-blocking one and waits for an event the same as if you were using the `OVERLAPPED` structure. **So, on your question of whether WriteFile would return ERROR_DISK_FULL before pending the IO, the answer is No.** The rationale of non-blocking calls is not to make disk operation return results faster, but to allow a single thread to do multiple I/O operations in parallel without the need to create multiple threads.

Comment: yes, usually filesystem driver which handle request always handle it asynchronous (despite and can detect synchronous request via `IoIsOperationSynchronous`). the IO manager if driver return `STATUS_PENDING` and file object was opened for synchronous I/O - simply wait for I/O complete before return to caller. so this not FS driver wait. however *non-blocking I/O* != *asynchronous I/O*. *non-blocking I/O* mean that request never wait and just **complete** when return to caller. *asynchronous I/O* also just return to caller, but it can be **not completed** when return. completion will be later

Comment: *same as if you were using the OVERLAPPED structure* - and using *OVERLAPPED* not make I/O asynchronous. it can be used and in synchronous I/O. simply in case asynchronous I/O use it mandatory, when in synchronous optional. are I/O is synchronous determinated by how  file object was opened (with which flag) and by api (some api always synchronous)

Comment: really we can not know are we just got `STATUS_DISK_FULL` and request complete synchronous with error or first we got `STATUS_PENDING` and only final status will be `STATUS_DISK_FULL` . can be both variants

Comment: So would that mean using multiple threads with no `OVERLAP` structure is the same performance as a single thread using `OVERLAP` structure?

Comment: @user3161924, a single thread handling multiple non-blocking operations (OVERLAPPED and WaitForMultipleObjects) is not the same performance but faster, because it avoids expensive context switching associated with multiple threads.